# Uniform bound in all choices of signs implies square sumability

Tags: functional-analysis, summation, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over the scalar field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Let $(x_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be a sequence of elements of $H$ such that there is some constant $A>0$ such that for every choice of a sequence of scalars $(\varepsilon_{k})_{k\geq 1}$ verifying $|\varepsilon_k|\leq 1$ and $\varepsilon_k =0 $ for all but finitely many $k\geq 1$, there holds
$$\left\Vert\sum_{k\geq 1}\varepsilon_k x_k\right\Vert\leq A.$$
How can it be deduced that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\Vert x_k\Vert^{2}<\infty$ ?
I can't even see how it would follow that $x_k\to 0$.
Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: hint: $\frac12(||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2)=||x||^2+||y||^2$. generalize that to $n$ independent $\pm$s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $r_1,r_2,\dots$ is a sequence of iid random variables with $P(r_j=1)=P(r_j=-1)=\frac12$. Writing out the square of the norm as an inner product you can verify the

> > **Generalized Polarization Identity** $E\left[\left|\left|\sum_{k=1}^nr_kx_k\right|\right|^2\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n||x_k||^2;$

hence $$\sum_{k=1}^n\left|\left|x_k\right|\right|^2\le A^2$$for every $n$.

**Context:** If that's interesting look up *random Fourier series* somewhere...